# Array mapping selected area of memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

While working on some other issue I was in need of creation of some pointer to arbitrary selected area of memory to be able to lookup the memory values. The experiments brings me to interesting issues and doubts.

Consider the following code:

```
//Some hypothetical memory area simulation
unsigned char data[4][4] =
{
    {0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11}, //Memory areas 0x00 - 0x03
    {0x22,0x22,0x22,0x22}, //Memory areas 0x04 - 0x07
    {0x33,0x33,0x33,0x33},
    {0x44,0x44,0x44,0x44},
};

// Structure that wraps byte array
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char TestArr1[4];
    unsigned char TestArr2[4];
    unsigned char TestArr3[4];
    unsigned char TestArr4[4];
}structure_t;

//Pointer to array of 4 chars
unsigned char (*MemLookup1)[4];

structure_t *StructLook;

int main(void)

{
    //Set both tested variables on first address of test array
    MemLookup1 = &data;
    StructLook = &data;
    //Some helpers to visualize results
    unsigned char * temp1, *temp2, *temp3, *temp4, *temp5;
    temp1 = &MemLookup1[0][0];
    temp2 = &MemLookup1[0][1];
    temp3 = &MemLookup1[0][2];
    temp4 = &MemLookup1[0][3];
    temp5 = &MemLookup1[1][0];

}
```

`MemLookup1` is declared as pointer to array of 4 chars (according to [THIS](http://cdecl.org/)). The results under debugger are surprising for me.

Values of temps are following:

`*temp1 = 0x11`
`*temp2 = 0x22`
`*temp3 = 0x33`
`*temp4 = 0x44`
`*temp5 = 0x11`  // At memory area 0x04

Values of

`StructLook.TestArr1` are `0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11`

`StructLook.TestArr2` are `0x22,0x22,0x22,0x22`

And so one.

The questions are:

1. How this feature of "additional" dimension for pointer is documented and explained? Note that [n][x] notation is used while pointer navigation, even that pointer is declared as single dimension array.
2. Why such memory alignment in pointer defined this way makes values being presented "Vertically" in memory? While iterating over first index i.e. `&(MemLookup1[1])` gives us address of `MemLookup1[0] + size of element pointed by pointer` and not as would be more natural, 2nd element of array or chars itself.
3. How can I create such pointer of array type that fulfil my requirements?
4. Last but not least: Why this is working perfectly fine when array is wrapped around structure? `StructLook` gives me exactly what I need, linear look up over memory cells.

EDIT

[Pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBb0a.jpg) from debugger.
Code is compiled against C (MinGW + GDB)

Comment: You can't assign `&data` to `MemLookup1`...

Comment: This will not compile in C++.  As a matter of fact, heed the errors that the compiler gives you --  don't try and "C-style cast" your way out of the error.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Choose one.

Comment: The code does not compile, thus what is surprising for me is that you get anything from your debugger...

Comment: `MemLookup1 = &data;` is ill-formed. Pay attention to compiler messages. Some common compilers report "warning" when the code is actually illegal; treat warnings as errors unless you are very sure they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is very C-like, and `gcc` compiles it successfully -- albeit with warnings -- so I'll answer for the C case.

To begin, I confirm that your `MemLookup1` is declared as a pointer to an array of four `unsigned char`.  I observe also that your `data` is declared as an array of four arrays of four `unsigned char`, so the type of the *elements* of `data` is the same type that `MemLookup1` points to.

Now consider this assignment:

```
MemLookup1 = &data;
```

The right-hand side is a pointer to an array of four arrays of four `unsigned char`, but the left-hand side designates a pointer to an array of four `unsigned char`.  These are not compatible types, therefore your code does not satisfy the constraints on the operands of a simple assignment operator (expressed by C2011 at 6.5.16.1/1), and hence the behavior of your program is undefined.  Similar applies to the assignment to `StructLook`.  The correct assignment would be `MemLookup1 = data`, `MemLookup1 = &data[0]`, or similar.

Although C does not define your program's behavior, if it can be compiled then we can indeed use a debugger to try to see what actually happens on some particular run.  C does not guarantee that it will be the same thing on every run, mind you, nor even that the program will not in some way be incompatible with the debugger, but hope springs eternal.

And here you fall down.  You claim that you get a different view of the data through pointer `MemLookup1` than you do through pointer `StructLook`, but the expressions shown in the image of your debugger window are not analogous.  For instance, you seem surprised that that `StructLook->TestArr1[1]` does not have the same value as does `*MemLookup1[1]`, but this is to be expected.

As we already established, `MemLookup1` is a pointer to an *array* of four `unsigned char`.  `MemLookup1[1]` therefore designates the *array* following `MemLookup1[0]` in memory.  In this case, the debugger shows that `MemLookup1` and `StructLook` are both aliases of `data`, so `MemLookup1[1]` is a pointer to `data[1]`, whereas `StructLook->TestArr1` is an alias of `data[0]`.  Array indexing has higher precedence than pointer dereferencing, and in this context, as in most others, an array-valued expression decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, so `*MemLookup1[1]` is equivalent to `data[1][0]`.  Contrast with `(*MemLookup1)[1]`, which is equivalent to `data[0][1]`.  Note also the similarity of the form of `(*MemLookup1)[1]` and the form of the declaration of `MemLookup1`.

How this relates to `temp1` ... `temp5` is unclear.  Your debug view does not show any expression related to those.

Comment: Yes. That's answer I was looking for. Thank you for focusing on delicate matters of C pointers instead of warnings/non-compiling issues, that are not an matter of this topic. Cheers!